# Write a number N as sum of K prime numbers

Tags: sum, primes

Is there any condition for writing a number N as sum of K prime numbers(prime numbers not necessarily distinct)?

Example: If N=6 and K=2 then we can write N as 6=3+3 whereas if N=11 and K=2 then we cannot  represent 11 as sum of two primes.

My Approach- I deduced the condition that If K>=N then we cannot represent N as sum of K primes.Also if K=1 then by primality testing we can check whether whether N is a prime number. Also by goldbach's conjecture for even numbers(except 2) N can be represented as sum of two prime numbers.

But the main problem is that I'm not able to predict it for K>=3.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths and should be asked on [maths.se]

Comment: @Mike:I'm asking here because the range of N and K is about 10^12 which becomes infeasible to check by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

1.Well, first list out all the prime numbers less than and equal to N.

2.Brute Force Approach with backtracking method.

ex :

N = 8

k = 2.

1. 2 2
2. 2 3
3. 2 5
4. 2 7
5. 3 3(Don't again consider 3 and 2)
6. 3 5.
   Done!

ex : 2

N = 12, 
k = 4

1. 2 2 2 2
2. 2 2 2 3
3. 2 2 2 5
4. 2 2 2 7
5. 2 2 3 3(don't again check for 2232)
6. 2 2 3 5.
   Done!

ex 3:

N = 11, 
k = 3

1. 2 2 2
2. 2 2 3
3. 2 2 5
4. 2 2 7
5. 2 2 11
6. 2 3 3(don't check again for 232)
7. 2 3 5
8. 2 3 7>11(don't check for 2311)
9. 3 3 3(don't again check the 32.. series.)
   10.3 3 5
   Done!